# Cuando usar computed y cuando usar methods en vue js

Tags: vue.js

Mi pregunta es simple no se cuando usar las funciones dentro de `computed` y cuando usar las funciones dentro de `methods` me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia entre una y la otra y cuando usarlas.

Comment: por favor tené cuidado al crear nuevas etiquetas. Tu reputación te lo permite, pero ahora todos pueden usar estas 2 etiquetas en inglés :-(

Comment: Ahora que miro la pregutna, porque mariano esta jugando a editar :p, me doy cuenta que no es basada en opiniones.. por lo menos tiene una respuesta base simple.. que despues se pueda hacer cualquier cosa en cualquier lado es otro problema...